# Angular SASS Selector with argument?

Tags: css, angular, sass

Reading through this Angular SASS code:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

:host(.column) {
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

What does the `:host(.column)` selector select.  Is it the host element when it has a `column` class attached to it?  Is that generally how we should interpret the argument passed in parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. The selector inside `:host()` must match the `:host` for the CSS to apply. According to the [Angular Component Styling documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host):

> Use the *function form* to apply host styles conditionally by including another selector inside parentheses after `:host`
>
> In this example the host's content also becomes bold when the `active` CSS class is applied to the host element.
>
> ```css
> :host {
>  font-style: italic;
> }
>
> :host(.active) {
>   font-weight: bold;
> }
> ```